# ExpressionEngine: Looping Through all the Entries in One Category

Tags: php, blogs, expressionengine

I'm using expressionengine to create a documentation site, using the weblog module. I have a number of categories, which contain subcategories. Categories and subcategories contain entries.

I want to create a page for each category that outputs a nested list of all the child entries and subcategories within in that parent category. There should be a breadcrumb at the top that shows the category hierarchy with links to the parent categories.

Here is my code:

```
<!-- url /docs/category/category_id -->

<!-- Breadcrumb -->
<!-- This works on the page template, but on the category template it shows all the categories -->
{exp:weblog:entries weblog="docs" }
    {categories}
        <a href="{path='/category'}?category_id={category_id}&category_name={category_name}&category_description={category_description}">{category_name}</a> >
    {/categories}
    {title}
{/exp:weblog:entries}

<!-- List of Categories -->
<!-- This shows ALL of the categories. I want it to only show the parent category and its children -->

{exp:weblog:categories style="nested"}
    <h1><a href="{path='weblog/category'}"{category_name}</a></h1> 
    {exp:weblog:entries category="{category_id}"}
        <a href="{path='weblog/page'}">{title}</a>
    {/exp:weblog:entries}
{/exp:weblog:categories}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**---EDIT---**

I have since written a plugin that solves this problem:
https://github.com/adambom/Category-Inheritance-Plugin-for-ExpressionEngine

**-------------**

Here's how I ended up doing it.

To get a list of subcategories, I pass a URL querystring parameter category_id, and run this:

```
<ul>
    {exp:query sql="SELECT cat_id as child_category_id, cat_name AS child_category_name FROM exp_categories WHERE parent_id = '<?php echo addslashes($_GET['category_id']) ?>' ORDER BY category_name ASC"}
        <li><a href="{path=/category/}?category_id={child_category_id}">{child_category_name}</a></li>
    {/exp:query}
</ul>
```

It only goes one level deep, but that's the best I could get it to do.

This code outputs all the entries (had to hard code the url):

```
{exp:weblog:entries category="<?php echo $_GET['category_id'] ?>"}
    <p><a href="/simulate/docs2/index.php/page/{entry_id}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:weblog:entries}
```

As a side note, I would not recommend using expressionengine for much of anything. For a blog, use Wordpress. For a documentation site, use a wiki. We are going to be switching to a rails site, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to write the code out for you, but I do have time to point you in (hopefully) the right direction. An ExpressionEngine developer by the name of Laisvunas has created several EE add-ons that deal with EE categories and their relationships to other categories and entries.

I won't link to them all, but his [developer page on Devot:ee](http://devot-ee.com/developers/laisvunas/) lists them all. The most popular category add-on that he's created is [Child Categories](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/child-categories/), which does much of what you're looking to do. If his (and other) add-ons can't help you with your problem, feel free to let us know.

Best of luck!

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I was looking for a way to write code in expression engine, not for a paid add-on. If there is a way to write an add-on, I should be able to write it myself, but I'm certainly not paying for it. -1

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, Adam! As a 'warning,' you should be aware that many EE add-ons are commercial (just as EE is). While you could consult the [EE API documentation](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/development/index.html) and build your own add-ons when needed, it's often much cheaper to spend < $100 on an add-on than to spend dozens of hours building out the same functionality. EE's core category tags leave a lot to be desired, hence the existence and popularity of the add-ons that I linked to. Best of luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Easily the best plugin for handling outputting categories (as many levels as you like) is [GWcode CatMenu](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-catmenu) which is free.